# How to get data from intersystems cache db through ODBC?

Tags: c++, qt, intersystems-cache

This is how i try to get a data from db:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QtCore>
#include <QtSql>
#include "iostream"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QODBC");
    db.setDatabaseName("DRIVER={InterSystems ODBC};SERVER=localhost;PORT=1972;DATABASE=USER;UID=_system;PWD=SYS; Unicode SQLTypes=1;");

    if (!db.open())
    {
        std::cout << "Error opening database" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        QSqlQuery query;
        if(query.exec("SELECT * FROM ACCOUNTS")){
            std::cout << "Select succses!" << std::endl;
        }

        while (query.next())
        {
            std::cout << "Getting results..." << std::endl;
            std::cout << query.value(0).toString().toStdString() << std::endl;
        }

        std::cout << "EXIT!" << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

And after query.exec(...) query.next() is always false but I really know that there is a data in the table. This behavior reproduce in the case when I try to get data from sample tables of Cache DB. What did i do wrong?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with this API, but shouldn't the query object be related in some way to the database object?... unless the API only allows one single connection at a time.

Comment: `exec()` returns false or true? What does `QSqlQuery::lastError()` return?

Comment: exec() returns true. lastError() returns: [Cache ODBC][State : S1106][Native Code 468] [C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\build-OD
BC-Desktop_Qt_5_3_0_MSVC2012_OpenGL_32bit-Deb] Fetch type out of range QODBC3: U
nable to fetch firstEXIT!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that connection config is wrong:

```
 QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QODBC");
 db.setDatabaseName("DRIVER={InterSystems ODBC};SERVER=localhost;PORT=1972;DATABASE=USER;UID=_system;PWD=SYS; Unicode SQLTypes=1;");
```

it should be:

```
 QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QODBC3");
 db.setDatabaseName("DRIVER={InterSystems ODBC35};SERVER=localhost;PORT=1972;DATABASE=USER;UID=_system;PWD=SYS; Unicode SQLTypes=1;");
```

Answer (score 0):

[as I said in the comments, I'm not familiar with this API Just looking through the documentation as I answer]

the documentation for the constructor of [QSqlQuery](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsqlquery.html#QSqlQuery-2)

> Constructs a QSqlQuery object using the SQL query and the database db.
>   If db is not specified, or is invalid, the application's default
>   database is used. If query is not an empty string, it will be
>   executed.

This means your query is opened on the *default database* (whatever that means).

Looking at the [QSqlDatabase documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsqldatabase.html):

> QSqlDatabase also supports the concept of a default connection, which
>   is the unnamed connection. To create the default connection, don't
>   pass the connection name argument when you call addDatabase().

however, you're giving a name argument in your addDatabase():

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QODBC");
```

... that means it is not the default connection.

My guess is that you should either:

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase();
```

or

```
QSqlQuery query=QSqlQuery(db);
```

Comment: I did this. However result is empty

Comment: @Daynin check the comment from UldisK in the original question... that might give a hint.